# nodejs get req.param from route

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get the url parameter of an url request from the front in my nodejs backend.

```
fetch(`http://localhost:9000/sent/5768797675645657`)
```

Here is my app.js file :

```
app.use('/sent/:id', require('./routes/sent'));
```

And my /routes/sent.js file :

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params)
})
```

How can I get the `console.log(req.params)` to work?

Answer (score 0):

So, `app.use` accepts two parameters: the portion of the URL, and a callback function.

In order to your app works, you've to change the `/routes/sent.js` and make it **exports** the function, so it can be used when you're requiring it.

Just change it to

```
module.exports = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params)
}
```

and you're ready to go!